# Converting MangoBlog to WordpressBlog

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Can anyone recommend a method that will convert a MangoBlog database to a Wordpress database?

Comment: you will have to write your own script and map each fields to make sense of the data once it is moved to mysql. Like Rahul said, mangodb is a tool that uses mongodb. Hence, it is difficult to auto convert without foreknowledge about the collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to convert mangodb to mysqldb...

First of all, do you know what is `mangodb`? Please check the tag wiki atleast and then frame the question.

`mangodb` is an ORM framework for `mongodb` and not a database system by itself. With that your question looks total invalid as it's illogical converting it to `mysql`, if you meant to convert your current `mongodb` system to `mysql` (which though not that clear from your post).

Answer (score -1):

I found this helpful. Have a look.
https://www.placona.co.uk/317/coldfusion/migrating-mango-blog-to-wordpress/